# Elegant way to define a function inside another function

Tags: r

I want to construct

```
f <- function(...) {
   g <- function(x) x ^ 2
   list(...)
}
```

so that I can invoke using `f(g(4))` and have `list(...)` result in `list(16)`.

In general I will define several temporary functions inside `f` that the user can invoke when calling `f(...)`.

I have experimented with `assign` and `newenvironment` but have just gotten more confused.  Help with an elegant solution is appreciated.

The reason for wanting this is that I want a function in the `Hmisc` package, `drawPlot` to be able to let the users specify generically named functions as input for building up a series of graphical elements, and I don't want to reserve these generic-type names.  E.g.:

```
d <- drawPlot(Curve(), Points())   # interactively make a curve and
                                   # a set of points
```

Comment: @TheTime Shouldn't it be `list(eval(substitute(...)))`?

Comment: @TheTime It could be convenient for passing arguments, similar to a `formula`. data.table has such a pseudo-function in `melt.data.table` (called `patterns`); it's not even a real function, just a shortcut for parsing args (I think).

Comment: `dplyr::select` has similar functionality, powered by the `lazyeval` package. You might get some inspiration from the [source code](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/master/R/select-vars.R)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm guessing you in fact need something more elaborate than this, but the following does what you've asked for in your supplied example:

```
f <- function(...) {
   g <- function(x) x ^ 2
   list(eval(substitute(...)))
}

f(g(4))
# [[1]]
# [1] 16
```

Or, if users may supply one or more function calls, something like this:

```
f <- function(...) {
   g <- function(x) x ^ 2
   h <- function(x) 100*x
   cc <- as.list(substitute(list(...))[-1])
   res <- list()
   for(i in seq_along(cc)) {
       res[[i]] <- eval(cc[[i]])
   }
   res
}
f(g(4), h(5))
# [[1]]
# [1] 16
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 500
```

Answer (score 3):

Very similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33737462/2954547) but I think maybe more extensible and closer to your original idea:

```
match.fun_wrapper <- function(...) {
  #   `match.fun` searches in the parent environment of the environment that
  # calls `match.fun`, so this wrapper is a hack to be able to search in
  # the current environment rather than the parent of the current environemnt
  match.fun(...)
}

f <- function(fun, ...) {
  g <- function(x) x ^ 2
  fun <- match.fun_wrapper(substitute(fun))
  fun(...)
}
```

If you wanted to do away with `match.fun`, you could also do away with the wrapper hack:

```
f <- function(fun, ...) {
  g <- function(x) x ^ 2
  fun(...)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like what you're trying to do is something like this:

```
f <- function(fun, ...) {
    g <- function(x) x ^ 2
    h <- function(x) x ^ 3
    i <- function(x) x ^ 4
    switch(fun,
           'g' = g(...),
           'h' = h(...),
           'i' = i(...))
}

> f('g', 3)
[1] 9
> f('h', 3)
[1] 27
> f('i', 3)
[1] 81
```

It's not obvious why you would want to, unless you're just trying to encapsulate functions with similar names inside different namespaces and using this as a hacky workaround for the fact R doesn't offer fully-featured classes. If that's the case, you can also just use actual namespaces, i.e. put your functions inside a package so they're called by `package::g(arg)` instead of `f('g', arg)`.

Comment: I've added my reasoning to the original question, which does not relate to fully-featured classes.  Since I want the arguments to `f` to be any number of function calls, I don't think your approach will do the trick.

Comment: You're right. It looks to me like Josh O'Brien's answer is best. I didn't see it when I posted and added this because ssdecontrol's does not work, returning an error if I try to run it.