# Call function with default Parameter on condition

Tags: r

I have a function `foo` that takes one argument and has a default parameter

```
foo <- function(b = 2) b
```

I want to call this function from another function `bar`.

```
bar <- function(a, b = NULL){
    a * foo(b = ???)
}
```

- **If `b` is provided in `bar`** I want to call `foo` with this parameter
- **if not** I want to call `foo` with its default parameter.

How can I do that?

(I couldn't find a good title for this question, so please change it if you know a better one.)

Comment: Maybe `a * if(is.null(b)) foo() else foo(b)`

Comment: is it not possible to keep same default value for `b` in `foo` as well as `bar` ?

Comment: @GKi yeah, sure this is a solution, but it is really very elegant and I hope I do it better

Comment: this might be helpful: -        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33737102/elegant-way-to-define-a-function-inside-another-function

Comment: @RonakShah this is not a good solution in my opinion. If something changes in this default parameter it needs to be changed in two places, which is error prone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `...` argument:

```
foo <- function(b = 2) b
bar <- function(a, ...) {
  a * foo(...)
}

bar(a=5)
bar(3, b=3)
bar(3, 7)
```

Comment: I had the same idea (`...`) but your solution is more elegant

Comment: Yeah, correct. This is the first thing that came to my mind as well, because it is so frequently used. I thought maybe there is another way, but sure, this is a good one.